# Facebook open graph "product" object type

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to find Open Graph objects with type 'products' that a user has interacted with. This object type is listed here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

However, if I use the graph API to find things that people have liked, the category 'product / service', which is not what I am looking for!.

Any clues?

Comment: The debug tool validates against the markup used in the Open Graph beta APIs, which is much stricter than the markup needed for a Like button, this is a known issue - there's an open bug report in facebook's bug tracker about this